# How to connect my docker compose file to localhost databse

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with 2 services: an apache airflow service and a postgres service for the airflow.
I have a postgres db running locally on port 5555. How can I connect my docker compose file to my local db?
My trimmed compose file looks like this:

```
version: 3
services:
  postgres:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  webserver:
    environment:
      - db_uri=path.localhost:5555/db_name
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    network_mode: "host"
```

When I run my docker like this I get this error
`(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`.
However if I change the env var from localhost to my inet ip address (`db_uri=path.123.456.789.012:5555/db_name`) and remove the `network_mode` option it works fine. How can I change it to be dynamic so if someone else runs the docker it will also work for them?

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect with HOST database using `localhost` or other service using service name in host network, in Host network service does not get IP, so every service will be available in host network and you can access other service using `HOST IP` or Docker host for window and Mac etc.

> If you use the `host network mode` for a container, that container’s
>   network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container
>   shares the host’s networking namespace), and the **container does not
>   get its own IP-address allocated**. For instance, if you run a container
>   which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s
>   application is available on **port 80 on the host’s IP address**.

If you want to access host database then you can pass HOST IP or you can use `host.docker.internal` but this does not work in linux, for mac and window it should work.

so you can try

```
version: 3
services:
  postgres:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  webserver:
    environment:
      - db_uri=HOST_IP:5555/db_name
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Is HOST_IP a special keyword? Because when I use it I get this error `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "HOST_IP" to address: Name or service not known`

Comment: No, `host.docker.internal` this is special in context of docker, while HOST IP is not. you can find HOST IP usig `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`

Comment: How do I use `host.docker.internal` in a docker compose file?

Comment: The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac.https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think
It should be like this:
webserver:

```
environment:

  - db_uri=postgres:5432/db_name

ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```